# are "all nets in $X$" well defined?

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, continuity

Denote $f:X\to Y$ as a function between topological spaces $X$ and $Y$. One good way for determining whether $f$ is continuous is to check the following statement.

> $f$ is continuous iff for every converging net $(x_\alpha)_{\alpha \in \Lambda}$ in $X$, one has $\lim_\alpha f(x_\alpha) = f(\lim_\alpha x_\alpha)$.

However, "every converging net" seems not to be a well defined set, since the index set $\Lambda$ could in principle be any directed set with any cardinality. I wonder what one needs to give this a well defined meaning. From what I read, Wikipedia says nothing about it.

Comment: Do you mean if the set of all nets is a set or a class but not a set ?

Comment: You can quantify over tings that do not lie in a set. You can say that $\emptyset$ is a subset of every set without there being a set of all sets.

Comment: You can *bound* the nets, and say: for every converging net $(x_\alpha)_{\alpha\in\Lambda}$ with $|\Lambda|\le |X|$, one has...

Comment: @Berci Is it easy to prove that your suggestion would yield "enough" nets? It isn't obvious to me.

Comment: Another example: A topological space $X$ is a $k-space$ if a subset $A$ is closed iff for every compact Hausdorff space $C$ and every continuous map $t:C\to X$ (called a *test-map*) the preimage of $A$ under $t$ is closed in $C$. Here we are quantifying over **all** continuous functions on **all** compact Hausdorff spaces. These form a proper class. However, for each k-space a set of test-maps can be defined such that $X$ has the final topology with respect to this set of maps. So we only need to *test* over this set. This is even sufficient in order to have a k-space.

Comment: @Berci It would seem the most basic $\Lambda$ examples would be, for $x\in X$: $\Lambda_x=\{U\subseteq X:U \text{ open and } x\in U\}$. This can potentially be larger than $X$.  I think that $\Lambda_x$ might be big enough, however.

Comment: @Berci and Thomas, I think what one needs for the proof is just to characterize points of the closure of a subset $A\subset X$ to then check that $f(\overline{A}) \subset \overline{f(A)}$. So a cutoff $|\Lambda|\le (something)$ could indeed be used, but they could at least have told me earlier!

Comment: Stefan and Dominic, I would very much profit from your comments if I had enough knowledge on the subject. From what I understand, there is a precise statement in terms of proper classes? I should check on that, I don't know almost anything in set theory.

Comment: Michael, I'm sorry but I actually didn't understand your comment...

Comment: Your condition above seems to assume that the spaces under consideration are Hausdorff (and thus convergent nets have unique limits).  The general condition would be the following: if $x$ is any limit point of $( x_\alpha )_\alpha$, then $f(x)$ is a limit point of $( f(x_\alpha) )_\alpha$.

Comment: @ArthurFischer:  It also works without unique limits. It is still equivalent.

Comment: @StefanH: Note that if a space is not Hausdorff the usage of "$\lim_\alpha x_\alpha$" by itself may be ambiguous.  In some places this denotes the set of all limits points of the net in question (_e.g._, Engelking's _General Topology_ uses this convention).  Where there is a unique limit you can "remove the curly-braces" and speak of its sole element.  But with this notational usage "$\lim_\alpha f(x_\alpha) = f(\lim_\alpha x_\alpha)$" refers to a set equality, which may not hold for continuous $f$.

Comment: @ArthurFischer: Ah, I see now that the OP formulated it the way he did. My mind already interpreted it as "if $(x_\alpha)\to x$, then $(f(x_\alpha))\to f(x)$" when I read the question :-) Besides I confused limit point with cluster point in your comment.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*(This answer echoes Michael Greinecker's comment above)*

There is not *set* of all convergent nets in a space, but this does not mean that this characterisation of continuity is flawed in any real way.  Certainly we can recognise whether or not some object is a convergent net in a the topological space $X$, and then verify that the required condition holds.  This would be done in the usual mathematical way: start with an arbitrary (and unspecified) convergent net $( x_\alpha )_\alpha$ in $X$, and by the properties of the spaces $X , Y$ and the function $f$ show that if $x$ is any limit point of the net then $f(x)$ is a limit point of the net $( f ( x_\alpha ) )_\alpha$.

This is not unusual in mathematics.  Consider the universal property of free groups:

> Given any set $S$, the *free group generated by $S$* is the unique (up to isomorphism) group $F_S$ having $S$ as a subset such that for any group $G$ and mapping $f : S \to G$ there is a unique homomorphism $\varphi : F_S \to G$ such that $f ( s ) = \varphi ( s )$ for all $s \in S$.

Although there is certainly no *set* of all groups, we can still verify that a group satisfies the universality property by takings an arbitrary (and unspecified) group $G$ and an arbitrary (and unspecified) function $F : S \to G$ and show that the required group homomorphism $\varphi : F_S \to G$ exists and is unique.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I finally got what Michael said! I only had a problem accepting that you could, at some point, say that you have checked some property for all elements of a class (that is not a set). But your comments have made my path clear as to what I should study. Again, thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

Additional remark ... The first textbook to embrace the use of nets for general topology was *General Topology* by J. L. Kelley.  It has an appendix "Elementary Set Theory" ... if examined carefullly we see its use of classes is more extensive than the NBG set theory.  It has subsequently been studied on its own as [**Morse-Kelley Set Theory**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morse%E2%80%93Kelley_set_theory):

> Morse–Kelley set theory is a proper extension of ZFC. Unlike von Neumann–Bernays–Gödel set theory, where the axiom schema of Class Comprehension can be replaced with finitely many of its instances, Morse–Kelley set theory cannot be finitely axiomatized.

So, for example, in Kelley we can construct the *completion* of a uniform space $X$ by starting: take the Class of all Cauchy nets in $X$, then form a Quotient by a certain equivalence Relation... [capitalized a la Conway]

In any given instance we can re-do the argument in ZF-style.  But Kelley (I guess) is saying, "Why bother with that?"

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As I am far away from undestading elementary set theory at all, this seems pretty hard for me to grasp. Nevertheless, it appeals as quite some interesting topic! Cheers.